# Better "System Settings" search functionality...?

Tags: kubuntu, search, system-settings

This should get me some results, no?

I know I saw some settings related to "classic" somewhere in there.

[image: Whaaaat.]

Answer (score 1):

By the KDE System settings handbook (Help > System Settings Handbook F1)

> Configuring System Settings
>
> The Configure icon in the toolbar allows you to change some System
>   Settings parameters. You can change from Icon View (default view) to
>   Classic Tree View.

[image]

The KDE UserBase System Settings page ( http://userbase.kde.org/System_Settings ) is telling:

> Search
>
> When the keyboard focus is in the icon window, you can type the first
>   few letters of any module name to select it.
>
> System Settings has a search function to help in hunting down a
>   setting. Simply type in a keyword in the Search field in the toolbar
>   and System Settings will display modules that contain the keyword and
>   hide those that don't.

The 'Classic Tree View' is a KDE System Settings view style not a KDE control module.

Comment: Oh, I see: "Search" only searches the titles of the sections in the tree. That makes it much clearer, thanks.